# How to use ng2Modules inside a project

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

I have a shared module in my app, I bundled all my components from the
shared folder in a single module.

What I need now is how do I import classes from that module?

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';

import { TreeModule } from 'angular2-tree-component';

import {
    GenericTabsComponent, DateNavigatorComponent,
    ErrorMessage, FavoriteListComponent, GenericContentComponent, GenericFormComponent,
    GenericListComponent, GenericLookupComponent, GenericPopupComponent, GlobalActionsComponent, LoadingComponent,
    UnitListComponent, UnitSubunitFavoriteItemComponent, UnitSubunitFieldComponent, UnitSubunitItemComponent,
    WeekstartComponent, AutoCompleteComponent, ChipsInputComponent, FilterboxComponent, GridCellActionComponent, GenericTabHeaderComponent,
    ActionGridComponent, ComboBoxComponent, TextareaComponent
} from './index';

@NgModule({
    id: "@app/components",
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule, AgGridModule, TreeModule],
    exports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, GenericTabsComponent, DateNavigatorComponent,
        ErrorMessage, FavoriteListComponent, GenericContentComponent, GenericFormComponent,
        GenericListComponent, GenericLookupComponent, GenericPopupComponent, GlobalActionsComponent, LoadingComponent,
        UnitListComponent, UnitSubunitFavoriteItemComponent, UnitSubunitFieldComponent, UnitSubunitItemComponent,
        WeekstartComponent, AutoCompleteComponent, ChipsInputComponent, FilterboxComponent, GridCellActionComponent, GenericTabHeaderComponent,
        ActionGridComponent, ComboBoxComponent, TextareaComponent],
    declarations: [GenericTabsComponent, DateNavigatorComponent,
        ErrorMessage, FavoriteListComponent, GenericContentComponent, GenericFormComponent,
        GenericListComponent, GenericLookupComponent, GenericPopupComponent, GlobalActionsComponent, LoadingComponent,
        UnitListComponent, UnitSubunitFavoriteItemComponent, UnitSubunitFieldComponent, UnitSubunitItemComponent,
        WeekstartComponent, AutoCompleteComponent, ChipsInputComponent, FilterboxComponent, GridCellActionComponent, GenericTabHeaderComponent,
        ActionGridComponent, ComboBoxComponent, TextareaComponent],
})
export class ComponentsModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ComponentsModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

This is the shared folder and the app structure looks like this.

> app->shared->components.module // here are all the components
>   app->main.page // a module for a page 
> app->users.page // a module
>   for another page 
> app->main.app.module //the root module

Now in `main.page` I need to import a component class, for example `GenericListComponent`, from the shared module to create a `ViewChild` and specify the type. From where do I import the class `GenericListComponent`? From the file location, or the import will look something like this?

```
import {GenericListComponent} from "@app/components"
```

Also, if I have 2 page modules with load children and they use components from shared. Where do I put my shared module in the main app component, or do I specify it as import in every module?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import your components from the file location, one thing though is that you can play with ES2015 export feature.

So imagine this, on your `GenericListComponent` folder create an `index.ts` with this:

```
export * from './generic-list.component';
```

This will basically re-export everything that is exported on your `generic-list.component`

Now on your `shared/` folder we create another `index.ts` to re-export everything again:

```
export * from './generic-list';
```

If you notice we are just referencing the `generic-list/` folder because inside of it there's an `index.ts`.

So with that in place now on your `main.page` you can this:

```
import { GenericListComponent } from './shared'
```

Now you just repeat the process for each folder inside your `shared/` folder and add multiple lines to the `index.ts` inside your `shared/`.